# Entity Framework select from a list of ids obtained from another E.F select query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

[image]

I'm trying to get ItemsEntity from a E.F query with a where statement. The condition gets item_id from another E.F query which returns more than 1 item_id.

```
var item_id = (from n in db.OrderDetail where n.OrderId == id select n.item_id);
var itemEntity = (from m in db.ItemsEntity where *m.item_id==item_id* select m);
```

Comment: Is OrderDetail related to ItemsEntity? If so that's a pretty simple single query using navigation properties.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `Contains` method when you want to use a collection in your `Where` clause

```
var listOfIds = (from n in db.OrderDetail where n.OrderId == id select n.item_id);
var itemEntity = (from m in db.ItemsEntity where listOfIds.Contains(m.item_id) select m);
```

Keep in mind that, with the above code, `itemEntity` variable will be collection. If you want single item, Use methods like `FirstOrDefault()` or `First()` as needed.

The above code can be written as a LINQ method chain as below as well

```
var listOfIds = db.OrderDetail.Where(n=>n.OrderId == id).Select(x=>x.item_id);
var itemEntity = db.ItemsEntity.Where(m=>listOfIds.Contains(m.item_id));
```

Comment: i need all the found item_ids to be used to get items respectively despite the number of item_ids

Answer (score 0):

Use First() or FirstOrDefault() at the end of first statement to make item_id variable an actual int type, not IQueriable as it is now.